# Solve the congruence $3x^2+x+8\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

How to find the solutions of this congruence? $$3x^2+x+8\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$$ 
I need to find the inverse of $3$, and there I have a problem.

Comment: $3 \cdot 4 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$

Comment: To discover the reciprocal of a number, just write down its powers modulo the modulus. The last power before you get to $1$ will be the reciprocal. So, modulo $11$, the powers of $3$ are $3$, $9$, $27\equiv5$, $15\equiv4$, $12\equiv1$, so that the reciprocal is $4$.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to form the square on the LHS :

$$12 \cdot(3x^2+x+8) \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$$

$$36x^2+12x+1+95 \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$$

$$(6x+1)^2 \equiv -95 \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$$

This means that $$6x+1 \equiv \pm 2 \pmod{11}$$

When $6x+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$ multiply by $2$ so :

$$12x \equiv 2\pmod{11}$$

$$x \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$$

Doing the same for the other leads to the other solution :

$$ x \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$$

Comment: I got $2$ and $5$.

Comment: me too,but most of them 1 and 5

Comment: Thanks . I have edited it .

Comment: you say this is a general method for quadratic equations modulo $p$ ?
you have $a x^2 + bx + c \equiv 0$ and you say there exists $e,f$ such that $$d(a x^2 + bx + c) \equiv (e x + f)^2 + dc - f^2$$.
$da = e^2$, $db = 2 f e$, ok it works. just choose $d$ such that $da$ is a square, set $e = \pm (da)^{1/2}$, $f = db e^{-1}$. not sure there exists another method either.

Comment: @user1952009 See my answer for the general method of solving $ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for odd primes $p$ (it's easy if $p=2$) and $p\nmid a$.

Comment: yes that's what I wrote, detect if $a$ is a square root, compute $\sqrt{ad}$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{split}
3x^2 + x + 8 = 0 [11] &\iff 3^{-1}(3x^2 + x + 8) = 0 [11] \iff x^2 + 4x + 10 = 0 [11] \\
&\iff (x + 2)^2 = -6 = 5 = 4^2 [11]
\iff x + 2 = \pm 4[11]\\
& \iff x = 2,5[11].
\end{split}
$$

This completing-the-square can be generalized to any modulus $p$, provided you know how to

- detect squares modulo $p$ (Hint: use the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol)), and
- compute square roots modulo $p$, say using something like [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

---

BTW, a brute-force algorithm for your problem has linear complexity in the modulus $p$, and this constitutes and "effective way" of solving the problem for small $p$ :). For example, in Python, you'd do:

```
for x in range(11):
    if (3 * x ** 2 + x + 8) % 11 == 0:
        print x
```

and get the output

```
2
5
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $p$ is an odd prime and $p\nmid a$, then $$ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod{p}\iff 4a\left(ax^2+bx+c\right)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$

$$\iff (2ax+b)^2\equiv b^2-4ac\pmod{p}$$

At this point, you're just left with finding the square roots of $b^2-4ac$ mod $p$.

---

In your case, $$3x^2+x+8\equiv 0\pmod{11}\iff (6x+1)^2\equiv 4\pmod{11}$$

In this case, the square roots of $4$ mod $p$ are simply $\pm 2$, so:

$$\iff 6x+1\equiv \pm 2\pmod{11}$$

$$\iff x\equiv \left\{\frac{2-1}{6},\frac{-2-1}{6}\right\}\equiv \left\{\frac{1}{6},\frac{-3}{6}\right\}\pmod{11}$$

$$\iff x\equiv \left\{\frac{12}{6}, -\frac{1}{2}\right\}\equiv \left\{2,-\frac{12}{2}\right\}\equiv \{2,-6\}\equiv \{2,5\}\pmod{11}$$

---

I'll explain about the general solution.

As I said, you're just left with finding the square roots of $b^2-4ac$ mod $p$ (after that it's simple).

So you're left with solving $X^2\equiv A\pmod{p}$ to find $X$,

where $X\equiv 2ax+b\pmod{p}$ and $A\equiv b^2-4ac\pmod{p}$.

A solution exists if and only if $\left(\frac{A}{p}\right)\in\{0,1\}$. This denotes the [Legendre Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). Finding it might require [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

If a solution exists, then see [this paper](http://course1.winona.edu/eerrthum/13Spring/SquareRoots.pdf) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus) for how to find the solutions.

If $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $X\equiv \pm A^{\frac{p+1}{4}}\pmod{p}$.

If $p\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, then either $X\equiv \pm A^{\frac{p+3}{8}}\pmod{p}$ or $X\equiv \pm 2^{\frac{p-1}{4}}A^{\frac{p+3}{8}}\pmod{p}$.

If $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, then it's complicated. You may need to apply either [Cipolla's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm) or [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), or see [the paper I linked](http://course1.winona.edu/eerrthum/13Spring/SquareRoots.pdf).